# php exec returning 127 because /bin/sh is getting "Permission denied" in apache chroot

Tags: php, exec, chroot

I have a php script that is trying to use exec (or shell_exec) to execute a binary on the system. The exec is failing with return code 127.

Return code 127 normally means command not found. So I made sure to use the absolute path to the binary. No change.

Apache is configure to run in a chroot using apache's ChrootDir.

I've made sure to copy the binary into the proper path in the chroot, as well as /bin/sh, and all the linked libraries needed for both of those.

Apache (and therefore php) are running as www-data. I've confirmed that www-data has read and execute permission to the binaries (including /bin/sh) and all the parent folders. To confirm that it is not a file permission issue, I've run the command using /bin/sh -c using sudo:

```
sudo -u www-data /chrootdir/bin/sh -c /chrootdir/path/to/binary
```

And that works without problems.

Using strace, I get this:

```
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/path/to/binary"], 0x7ffe436b3618 /* 11 vars */) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Just to confirm that the permission issue is for the sh binary (and the one in the chrootdir) I tried renaming /chrootdir/bin/sh to something else and did the strace again and now it complained about file not found.

So, I now know that the problem is with the access to /chrootdir/bin/sh when run via php through apache, but is not a permission of the www-data user.

I'm not sure what to try next.

This is running on Debian 10, apache 2.4.38, and php 7.3.11.

I've cleared open_basedir, and I've also cleared disable_functions.

I've confirmed that apache is unconfined by apparmor, but disabled it anyways.

Finally, if I disable the apache chroot, this does work.

So my question is there any other restriction somewhere that might be stopping apache from doing this?

Comment: That's not a good test. Try instead `sudo -u www-data chroot /chrootdir /bin/sh -c /path/to/binary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael Hampton's comment above, I tried using the chroot command to simply chroot to /chrootdir as root. I was not able to. I would get:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Permission denied
```

I also tried as he suggested to execute /bin/sh -c /path/to/binary (but as root since www-data can't use chroot command). And that gave the same permission denied error.

The fact that it would properly execute when I just used sudo -u www-data /bin/sh ..., but not with the chroot command, this meant that the issue must be with the linked libraries.

Upon further investigation, the /chrootdir/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 library was not executable. Making it executable fixed the problem.